# Align elements inside an <a> tag vertically

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a>` tag (which is part of multiple `<li>` tags). In the `<a>` tag I have an `<i>` tag and some text - the text of the link.

What I would like to achieve is to have the icon on top and the text under it (and then centered). So it would look like:

```
   ICON
MYTEXTHERE
```

However they are always placed next to each other. I tried using `display: inline-block` - because my `<a>` is *inline* and the content inside should be *block* but without success.

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/6mg4vt77/5/

*Edit:* Thanks for the answers but sadly I forgot to mention that I must support IE9.

Comment: Note that `<i>` tag should be used only for text content. Use of a more appropriate tag type should be the way to go.

Comment: I am using `<i>` as per the Font Awesome examples

Comment: I have this on that which itself is inside that is not a good practice for SOF questions. its better you provide your markup.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<a href="/items/bluetooth" style="display: inline-block; text-align:center">
  <i class="fa fa-bluetooth"></i>
  <br>
  BLUETOOTH
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6mg4vt77/7/

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer**, set the icon to 100% wide and center everything in the anchor.

```
a{
  text-align: center;
}

a .fa {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zw0mfryo/)

**Modern Method**

Flexbox:

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="/items/bluetooth">
  <i class="fa fa-bluetooth"></i> BLUETOOTH
</a>
```

Comment: I don't mention the prefixed version because it's not necessary for the purposes of this answer.

Comment: In general I would prefer the answer as flexbox is the future (AFAIK). Unfortunately I must be able to support IE9. I should have stated this in the question, my bad.

Comment: What if my icon is an actual png image? Isn't setting the width to 100% then going to stretch it?

Comment: If you wanted to use an image you should have asked a different question. I wouldn't use an actual *inline* image...I'd use a background image.

Comment: I just want to consider all possible options before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your test case I'll use two nested `<span>` within the anchor, one for the icon and the second for the text. Then I'll give them both `display:block`. That way one should position itself on top of the other. Finally you can nest the `<i>` tag within the first `<span>`, like so:

```
<a href="/items/bluetooth" style="display: inline-block;">
  <span style="display:block;"></span>
    <i style="width:100%;text-align:center;" class="fa fa-bluetooth"></i>
  </span>
  <span style="display:block;">BLUETOOTH</span>
</a>
```

Live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/6mg4vt77/10/

Comment: What if my icon is an actual png image? Isn't setting the width to 100% then going to stretch it?

Comment: In such case You shouldn't use an `<i>` element at all.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a div like so:

```
<div class="link" style="width:90px;text-align:center;">
<a href="/items/bluetooth" style="display: inline-block;">
<i class="fa fa-bluetooth" style="text-align:center;"></i><br> BLUETOOTH
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu ddcolumns">
<li><a href="#">Main3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

That should fix your problem.

PS: You can always change the width in the div to your liking, even with % :-).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as titled, "Align elements inside an <a> tag vertically", this https://jsfiddle.net/cdLp61ad/1/ is what I use to:

- middle-align linktext vertically
- and horizontally
- Keep the clickable area under control (full height and width)

*(don't be fooled by tabley-looking stuff, it's not tables!)*

```
ul {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;    /* all cells same width */
  margin: 0 auto;         /* Optional */
}

a {
  display: block;     /* Makes line-height work */
  line-height: 4em;   /* Control HEIGHT of clickable area here */
  padding: 0 16px;    /* Control WIDTH of clickable area here */
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  background: bisque;         /*just for visualisation*/
  border: 1px dashed orange;  /*just for visualisation*/
}
```

HTML nesting is done the 'usual' way:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a ... >
```

### Multiple-lines in linktext leaves a gap, sorry

I'm still working on this...

- Negative margin doesn't seem to help
- The technique uses display: heavily so playing further with that 'may cause unexpected behaviour'
- I'd probably try relative positioning next but I sure did give up last time, All my horizontal menus are on-liners!

### See also:

- OLD tech: Alignment how-to and how-not-to at [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/)
- NEW tech: Promising info at sitepoint.com re [Giving Floasts the Flick](http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/) and [Migrating to Flexbox](http://www.sitepoint.com/migrating-flexbox-cutting-mustard/?utm_source=sitepoint&utm_medium=nextpost&utm_term=html-css)
- You CAN [wrap A-tags round block elements in HTML5](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wrapping%20blick%20elements%20insode%20inline%20elements&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=jcJ_Vo32GYKdaKqNs6gJ)

Answer (score -1):

Put the text you want to display into another HTML element, e.g. `<p>`. To center the icon, wrap it into an element and style it with `text-align`.

```
<p style="text-align: center">
     <a href="/items/bluetooth" style="display: inline-block;">
         <i class="fa fa-bluetooth" ></i> 
         <p>BLUETOOTH</p>
     </a>
</p>
```

Comment: `<p>` elements should be used only for phrasing content as stated by html5 specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html)