# Horizontally align a div (having background image) inside an <a> tag

Tags: html, css

This is a continuation of [Align elements inside an <a> tag vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470462/align-elements-inside-an-a-tag-vertically)

The problem which I have is that in some cases I do not have an icon coming from the `<i>` tag but I have a background image

So the markup goes like this:

```
<a href="/accessoires" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="accessoires"></div>
    <span style="display: block ;">ACCESSOIRES</span>
</a>
```

The `accessoires` CSS class is taking care of the image (via `background`, coming from a sprite).

But as you can see the `<div>` is not centered, it is aligned to the left.

[image: div aligned left but should be centered]

So what I am looking for is a way to horizontally center align a div inside an `<a>` tag.

P.S. it must not be a `<div>` - as long as I am able to keep my CSS/background/sprite magic

Looking for an IE9 compatible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't semantically correct to place a div inside an a element before `html5`.

I'd recommend using an `i` element for the icon because that is a commonly used convention.

The `text-align: center;` only applies to inline elements and that's why it doesn't center the div in your example. Using `display: inline-block;` should do the trick.

If the icon didn't use a sprite-sheet you could set the div to be 100% wide and use `background-position` to center it.

Comment: AFAIK as of HTML5, a div can be placed inside an `<a>` tag so it should be semantically correct. `background-position` is not an option as I am already using it to define the exact location of the image inside the sprite. Or am I misunderstanding you here?

Comment: I missed the part about the image being loaded from a sprite-sheet. In that case it would be necessary to have an element inside the a element that crops the correct image from the sheet. My bad. Width 100% is not an option. That leaves a couple options for the centering: ser the div/i element to be `display: inline;` or inline-block. Another option is to set the a element as `position: relative;` and the i/div to `position: absolute; left: 50%;`.

Comment: I'd recommend using i elements for the icons because thats a common solution although as you pointed out the div is not semantically incorrect anymore. :)

Comment: Setting the div to be `display: inline;` causes the image to disappear. But using `display: inline-block` seems to render it correctly and also centered. What exactly causes the difference? Is it because my image has already defined height and that is why it has to be in a 'block'?

Comment: You're on the right tracks. The inline elements height is defined differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967613/height-style-property-doesnt-work-in-div-elements

Comment: Cool, thanks. If you update your answer according to our comments I would mark it as accepted.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for reminding. Now the next one with a similiar problem doesn't have to crawl through the comments. Glad I could help! :)